# Using Regex Inside Property Setter

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to know how to combine properties and regex. Here's the property:

```
public string NameFormal        
{       
    get {return nameFormal;}    
    set     
    {   
        nameFormal = value;
    }   
}
```

I'd like to use the setter to validate input using a regex pattern that I already have. I could write a separate bool function to yes/no the match. But how do I do that inside a property that returns a string?   Appreciate the help.

I'm using VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to check the value against a regex before setting it in the setter?

```
public string NameFormal        
{       
    get {return nameFormal;}    
    set     
    {   
        string pattern = "^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$"; //input your regex here
        if (Regex.IsMatch(value, pattern))
        {
            nameFormal = value;
        }
        else
        {
            //didn't match
        }
    }   
}
```

Be careful putting logic like this in setters however as it can get confusing when setting a property and it silently failing, I suggest throwing or having something to alert the user / programmer that setting this variable has failed.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Yes, I want to check the value vs. a regex before setting it in the setter. Perhaps I need to validate the user's form input with a bool function and then separately invoke the setter with the clean input? Otherwise, as you note, the property isn't really suited for a boolean yes/no back-and-forth with the user.

Comment: @user1695788 That approach will probably cause you less headaches in the long run.

Comment: Got it. The setters are still good for correcting user input without any more interaction with the user like reformatting a phone number. Thanks much.

Comment: By the way there's a little checkmark next to the answer you can check if this solved your problem.  I just noticed you haven't accepted any answers with 9 questions.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer